# Pairing teams up for competition

Tags: php, website-design

So i visited this site http://fantasy.premierleague.com/ and in this when i go to the fixtures, i was thinking, how did the developer designed this so that the new fixtures get generated on its own?
For eg if i am having 10 teams(say), and i am competing them in some competition(say football) then how do i design my thing so that after each week a new set of fixtures is generated, shall i change the page after every week, and change it manually, or how do i do it. Say, i am having all my fixtures in hand, i.e. i know every weekly fixture, then how do i design the whole thing. It will not be nice to edit the page every time i need to change the fixtures.
I am still a beginner, who have practiced a bit of PHP, so kindly help!

Comment: Although your question is about a website I've flagged it for a moderator to move it to stackoverflow.com. The solution lies in the programming to firstly create fixtures, and secondly, update them ever week. You should get a good answer there.

Comment: @paulmorriss - the question as stated isn't really suitable for Stack Overflow. It's a design question and there's no code. Programmers *might* be a better place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**High Level answer:**

You'll build a program that runs on the server to generate the matches and keep track of the outcomes. The html page will then change dynamically at load time based on the program running in the background that's keeping track of the matches. You can store all of the information in a MySQL database. The PHP program will execute the logic and ferry the information from the database to the end-user. You can accomplish this using PHP/MySQL.

Start down the path, then ask specific programming questions as stackoverflow.com as paulmorriss suggests.